# MFSlide Menu Not work when app implement will enter foreground method

Tags: ios

My question is when my app goes in background and after some time when app come in foreground state my MFSlide menu that i use to  split screen in not working can you please help me I used following code to implement left menu function:-

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];

    UIViewController *leftSideMenuViewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"DemoLeftViewController"];

    container = [MFSideMenuContainerViewController
                                                    containerWithCenterViewController: self.window.rootViewController
                                                    leftMenuViewController: leftSideMenuViewController
                                                    rightMenuViewController: nil];


    self.window.rootViewController = container;


    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

Comment: Check `MenuState`. If it is closed, then set it to `MFSideMenuStateLeftMenuOpen` or vice-versa.